# Upgraded an engraving but it isn't available to me

Tags: assassins-creed-odyssey

I have upgraded a couple of engravings at Hephaistos's Workshop but they are not appearing as an option at the blacksmith or within the list of engravings in the inventory... Does anyone know why this is happening? Hopefully not a bug.

I just upgraded to "+28% poison damage" and "+35% CRIT damage":

[image]

When I visit a Blacksmith and try to select the engraving:

[image]

If I go into Inventory -> Engravings list:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're reading the "learn engravings" screen (your first screenshot) in Hephaistos's Workshop wrong. This seems to display the list of engravings (and levels thereof) that you're *eligible to learn*, not those that you already know. Looking at the other engravings available in the displayed screenshots, it looks like every single one is one level lower than what you see in the "learn engravings" screen, not just the two you circled. The Inventory screen (your third screenshot) shows the ones you know, and this seems to match the Engraving screen.

Comment: Ah, I see, I'm misreading the interface... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not all engravings are available on all items. For example, the `+ CRIT Damage` is only available on the following items:

- All Melee Weapons
- Bows
- Head Armor
- Arm Armor
- Torso Armor

([Source](https://gamewith.net/assassins-creed-odyssey/article/show/707), search for "Crit damage")